# (How) can I run a microcontroller and DC motor from the same battery?

Tags: microcontroller, motor, dc

I have a microcontroller (a PIC10F200) that I'm using to control a DC motor. It's a very simple circuit. A button is pushed and the pic sends output for certain increments of time. The thought is to use the microcontroller output to control a hexfet which is controlling a DC motor.

The question is:

(How) can I run the DC motor and microcontroller from the same 9V battery?

Comment: Most microcontrollers require 5V max., so you need a circuit that runs the microcontroller from 5V (a voltage regulator) and run the motor from 9V. The catch is in the specs of the FET you want to use. Not all FET's will saturate with a 5V gate-source voltage.

Comment: Given a hexfet such as the IRLB3034PBF which can be activated by 1V how do I run the motor and the hexfet from the same battery without having the microcontroller compromised? Even with different power sources using a Darlington gate the microcontroller choked when the DC motor was activated.
http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlb3034pbf.pdf

Comment: Where did you read the 1V for activation, because I can't find it. In my opinion it is more like 2.2V for a 1A current. Also the gate capacity is *huge* so you're introducing another challenge if you use this FET. This is a beast, what current does your motor draw anyway, the transistor can do 200A!

Comment: I read the specs wrong... It is higher as you point out. It's only for a small hobby motor drawing ~5V @ ~1A<. I would be happy to use another hexfet if you can recommend one. These hexfets may be overkill but it was my understanding that in contrast to other mosfets this hex fet could be driven by simple TTL out such as from a pic.

Comment: I may also use a mosfet such as the STP36NF06L.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is nothing fundamental preventing the sharing of the battery.

Of course, the battery must be properly rated for your load (max. current and series resistance).  The microcontroller needs a regulator and some passive filtering to isolate the voltage variations that the load will induce due to its varying current draw.

Regarding layout, ensure that motor current does not flow through the traces/wires related to the micro.  In this particular design, that means that the battery's ground must first go to the n-mosfet's source, and from there to the micro and its regulator (instead of 1st going to the micro), or even better a star topology, with the center of the start as close as possible to the battery's negative terminal.  Otherwise you'll get a noticeable ground bounce that will damage/reset the micro.

Additionally, keep all current loops as small as possible to reduce EMI.  In this case, this means keeping the wire that goes to the motor twisted/tied to the wire that comes back, and close to the mosfet as it follows the current loop.  This also applies to the gate circuit, but this is less critical.

You should put a series resistance at the gate to limit the current draw from your micro's pin during transitions.  A pull-down would also help in keeping the motor off at power-up.

Don't forget the flywheel diode in parallel with the motor, to prevent huge voltage spikes when turning off the mosfet.  You could also consider a snubber circuit to reduce transient spikes.

In your micro, make use of the watchdog timer so that the motor does not stay on if a hang occurs during an on time.  A more robust failsafe would be a high pass circuit at the gate, but this means your pwm duty cycle cannot be 100%.