# Confusion why MAX98357 won't get full power when shared with ESP32

Tags: power-supply, esp32, hobbyist

I have what I thought was an easy circuit, but it is not behaving as I expected.  I have an ESP32 devkit1 and a MAX98357 breakout board that I am trying to run together.  The MAX98357 breakout is connected to a speaker so I am trying to dive it from 5V. When I was developing and running the pair with my desktop the audio that came out of the DAC was very clear and loud. The configuration as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOT0sV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The issue was when I tried to connect it to an external power supply from an animatronic device to add some audio effects.  When it was powered on it all worked but the audio was quite soft. The power from that was 12V at 4A, and I put it through an Adafruit UBEC DC/DC Step-Down (Buck) Converter to get it down to 5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWKnG4.png)</sup>

My understanding is that Vn can provide 5V from the USB, or it can power the board from 5V unregulated.  Why would the configuration taking DC from the buck converter not react the same?  I assume that since its a parallel circuit at that point that some sort of division of the current is happening.  The buck converter should be able to provide 3A so wouldn't that be enough to cover things?  Is there a better way to configure this circuit?

**Update**:  I did confirm the voltages during the operation and they both look like they are about 5V when its operating.  I am now wondering if the issue is how I have my cricut spliced in.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Bwds.png)</sup>

I think this might be what I am screwing up.  I am vaguely aware that parallel circuits will divide the current between the paths.  Is that more or less what I have here?

Comment: The input signal level and the volume control setting determine the maximum undistorted output power. If the 5VDC drops then the maximum output power will be less.

Comment: I checked your suggestion with the voltage and updated the post.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I might be more or less looking at this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/509234/352590 situation.