# UART over USB for radio transciever board

Tags: usb-device, usb-host

I am creating a telemetry radio that operates over UART, but I want to interface via a USB port so the same connection can be used between the flight computer and the onboard radio and between the ground control radio and the ground control computer. I have found various chips from FTDI and Silicon Labs that can be used by the radio boards to convert USB to UART, but I haven't been able to find a good chip to use on the flight computer board to convert UART into USB.

Is there an easy way to take a UART signal in and output a USB signal that can be decoded back into UART?

Comment: `take a UART signal in and output a USB signal` ... I think that you may be misunderstanding what USB to UART converters do ... when you plug the converter into a USB port on a computer, the converter adds a hardware serial port to the computer

Comment: Definitely possible, I am pretty new to this. I wanted to use USB to connect the flight computer to the radio board so that the same radio board design and connector can be used on the vehicle end and the ground control end, and this seemed like the way to do it.

Comment: @jsotola so I guess the question is how do I connect two microcontrollers that communicate using a UART signal over a hardware USB port, while retaining the ability for the radio to plug into a computer over the same hardware USB port?

Comment: why USB? ... connect the serial pins between the microcontrollers directly ... use a level converter if the voltages are different ... maybe I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: please add a block diagram to your post ... use the schematic editor that is available when you edit your post ... click `save and insert` after the drawing is done ... result looks like this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/685755/confusion-why-max98357-wont-get-full-power-when-shared-with-esp32

Comment: USB is not just a different way of signaling stuff. It's an entirely different protocol. The device which acts as a USB 'slave' and gives you UART signals on the other end is not 'reversible', because the USB protocol needs a 'host' on one end of the link and a 'device' on the other end. A USB 'host' is a significantly more complex beast compared to a 'device'. So although what you want is technically possible (by creating a dumbed-down USB 'host' with a UART interface) it's not as easy as dropping in a USB-UART for the 'device' end.